# Postgres: Select value from array

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have an asset database and different types of assets each have a unique set of custom fields
A query displays following table and displays name and value of all custom

| asset_id | asset_type | custom_fields |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Type A | "BreakdownProvider"="CompanyC","SerialNo"="1234","Model"="ABC" |
| 456 | Type B | "SerialNo"="567","Model"="XYZ","BreakdownProvider"="CompanyD" |
| 789 | Type C | "Model"="ModelA","Capacity"="120kg" |
| 321 | Type C | "Model"="ModelB","Capacity"="240kg" |

How do I create a query that will show me just the value of one custom field name

| asset_id | asset_type | model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Type A | ABC |
| 456 | Type B | XYZ |
| 789 | Type C | ModelA |
| 321 | Type C | ModelB |

Thanks in advance

Comment: The values in `custom_fields` do not look like a Postgres array or a Postgres JSON array either. To your question add the table definition.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand Which type custom_fields is?

Comment: Besides the fact that this is hard to query, performance will be terrible as well when looking for something in the customer_fields. Can only give you one advice: fix your datamodel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your custom_fields you can use a jsonb type and turn your string into a json type like this:

```
{"BreakdownProvider":"CompanyC","SerialNo":"1234","Model":"ABC"}
```

Once this is done, in postgres it is very simple to access the fields of a json with the "->" operator

```
select custom_fields->'Model' from table;
```

Comment: Great thanks sorted it and sorry I should have said string not array